# Check Java version/type from within code

Tags: java, version

Basically, I'm trying to determine whether a user is using an IBM JDK or Oracle JDK from within the code itself, but can't think of an elegant solution outside of running command line arguments and using a string tokenizer.
Does anybody know of an API or native method of discovering these details?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Identify the current JVM with Java or JVMTI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583975/identify-the-current-jvm-with-java-or-jvmti)

Answer (score 6):

For vendor and version

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.vendor"));
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just use

```
String vendor=System.getProperty("java.vendor");
String version = System.getProperty("java.version");
System.out.println(vendor);
System.out.println(version);
```

This will give your `jdk` version with the vendor.

Out put:

```
Oracle Corporation
1.7.0_25
```